# Error with MultiValue parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I made a couple of reports that are using a data-source for the parameter values. The same query is specified in available values and default values, so that I can select multiple values at once. The query usage is like this:

```
WHERE (Column.Name IN (@Parameter))
```

However, I get this error:

[image: screenshot of the error]

Any ideas what could it be? Other reports using same method work fine, but with this one it doesn't.

Comment: Assuming both queries are for the same Database and Table, check in the *Report Parameters* menu that the parameters type and specifications are the same as in the base report.

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256925/ssrs-multi-value-parameter-using-a-stored-procedure

Comment: Both querys are the same database but uses couple of tables where the params goes in :) the data types are the same

Comment: Lan Preston - no it doesnt :) but thanks for triyng

Comment: It sounds like something is being passed in the parameters (or otherwise) that turns your SQL invalid. Run SQL Profiler against your database then run your report to see what SQL is hitting the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i Ran the SQL Profiler and seen that the errors came from the code that is looking is the param a null (@param is null) that was the mistake because i allready sead in the options to now allow null

Thank you Chris Latta you helped me allot :)