# How to do a SQL search when the column values have commas in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have this SQL:

```
Select * from Table1
Where instructor_name in (@Instructors)
```

The problem is that the instructor name in the table is in the format LastName, FirstName.  I'm not sure how to handle the comma so that I can find "Schmoe, Joe" in the database.  Does anyone have an idea how I can do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail about what your parameter values are going in to this? Are you trying to use a multi-value parameter?

Comment: I want to be able to use a multi-values parameter as I see the clients wanting to report on more than one instructor at a time.  Both the parameter and the column values will have the "firstname, lastname" format.

Comment: Is the query embedded in the report? If so, can you use a stored procedure? You can make this work with a stored procedure - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256925/ssrs-multi-value-parameter-using-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can send in a list of params and the create a function to break the values into a table in which case the following commands will work:

WHERE
    (@CommaLists IS NULL OR SomeTable.SomeValue IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.IR_CreateIntIDTable(@CommaList)))

Comment: It doesn't sound like the OP has a column (or parameter) with multiple values. If so, they should use the Multi-value parameter option available in SSRS.

Comment: I do want to be able to have the client search on more than one instructor at a time, if that is what they want, if that helps any.