# Allow multiselect on a CSV column in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, csv, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to make a parameter multiselect on a CSV column in a report, but I am not sure how to do this or if it's even possible. Example dataset that is returned:

```
|  ID  |  Name  |      Types      |
|  1   |  Test  |  Type A, Type B |
```

The current dataset is using something like this in the `WHERE` clause for the parameter:

```
WHERE Types LIKE '%' + @Types + '%'
```

This works fine as a single select, but of course doesn't work for multiselect. How can I make it so the parameter will allow multiple values and still search this CSV column? I wish something like `WHERE Types LIKE IN '%' + @Types + '%'` would work, where it basically would end up as `WHERE Types LIKE IN ('%Type A%, %Type B%')`. Or is there a better way I can display the column so it appears CSV even if the SQL is not doing it? I would still want it to display all the values and only see if the selected type is in the list, so if the parameter is set to `Type B` it should still show `Type A, Type B` for `ID = 1`. I know CSVs are generally disliked in SQL, but it seems to be a frequent thing that's asked to make CSV columns and then allow multiselect on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS multi-value parameter using a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256925/ssrs-multi-value-parameter-using-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

there would be 2 posibilities
    (1) your filter would have single value like 'Type A'
    (2) your filter would have multiple values like 'Type A, Type B'
    here i am giving solution for both 1 and 2.
    here i have used #table to make it understand easy

dummy data would be:

```
If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#temp') Is Not Null
Begin
    Drop Table #temp;
End

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#temp') Is Null
Begin
    Create Table #temp
    (
         Id         Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key
        ,Name       Varchar(100)
        ,Types      Varchar(2000)
    )
End

Insert Into #temp(Name,Types) Values
('Test','Type A, Type B'),
('Test1','Type A, Type C'),
('Test2','Type B'),
('Test3','Type C, Type A'),
('Test4','Type C');

Declare  @TypeFilter        Varchar(2000)
```

posibility 1:

```
Select   @TypeFilter = 'Type C'

Select  *
From    #temp As t With (Nolock)
Where   (',' + t.Types + ',') Like ('%,' + @TypeFilter + ',%')
```

posibility 2:

```
Select   @TypeFilter = 'Type C, Type B'

Select  Distinct
        t.*
From    #temp As t With (Nolock)
        Join dbo.UDF_GetSplitValues(@TypeFilter,',') As p On (',' + t.Types + ',') Like ('%,' + p.stItems + ',%')
```

here for posibility 2, I have used table-value function which returns CSV values into table and applied join with primary table.

hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try your where clause as

```
WHERE PATINDEX('%' + Types + '%',@Types)>0
```