# SSRS Passing Multiple value parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services

Am trying to pass a multi value parameter to a Stored Procedure from the SSRS report.

After following the query 
[SSRS multi-value parameter using a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256925/ssrs-multi-value-parameter-using-a-stored-procedure)

I've made the stored procedure accept the CSV list by modifying the query as 
value `IN (@CampaignID)`

I've added the `Join(Parameters!TerritoryMulti.Value, ",")` at dataset parameters as this would pass the values as CSV.

Still, I see that, only single (first value selected) value is being passed to Stored Procedure from SSRS despite the number of values selected.

This is how, I checked the parameter being passed from SSRS.

Added the Statement: `Insert into RF.Dashboard.ErrorMessages values (1, @CampaignID)` in the stored procedure.

After running the report in SSRS. I see the following entries in the table.

```
msgID Message
1   1
1   1
1   1
```

Please help me understand what am I missing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256925/ssrs-multi-value-parameter-using-a-stored-procedure

Comment: First thing would be to add a simple textbox somewhere on your report with the expression set to `=JOIN(Parameters!TerritoryMulti.Value, ",")` this will show you what is being passed to the proc. If this looks correct then test your proc manually (thru SSMS) setting the results of this textbox as your parameter value.

Comment: Thanks Alan. That helped me. There was an issue with my stored procedure. I was using nvarchar to hold the parameter passed rather than varchar(max). Which I later changed and things work.