# ssrs multiple values parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I know this question has been asked several times before, but the answers I have found do not work for my code, so I am posting it here.  My query is in SQL Server v17.0.  I have an SSRS report with a code parameter, but it only shows values when 1 code is selected.  Under parameter props, I checked the 'allow multiple values' option, but that did nothing.  Any suggestions?

```
create procedure [roo].[get_cc_serv]
( @upc_code varchar(max) = ''   )
as
select 
acct_num = ser.account_number,
status_change_date = crd.date_status_chg,
upc14 = isnull(crd.upc_14, '-')

from fact.fact_cc_serv ser
join dim.dim_cc_card crd on 
ser.dim_cc_cardholder_key = 
crd.dim_cc_cardholder_key

where ser.end_date = 99991231
and crd.upc_14 is not null
and crd.upc_14 not like 'Z%'
and crd.upc_14 in (@upc_code)
```

Comment: You cannot use IN with a stored procedure.  See specifically: "The data source cannot be a stored procedure. Reporting Services does not support passing a multivalue parameter array to a stored procedure."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/aa337292(v=sql.100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the procedure for this forces the multi-select to be treated as a single value.

If you embed the SQL query in your report instead of using a proc, it should work:

Put this into a dataset in the report:

```
select 
acct_num = ser.account_number,
status_change_date = crd.date_status_chg,
upc14 = isnull(crd.upc_14, '-')

from fact.fact_cc_serv ser
join dim.dim_cc_card crd on 
ser.dim_cc_cardholder_key = 
crd.dim_cc_cardholder_key

where ser.end_date = 99991231
and crd.upc_14 is not null
and crd.upc_14 not like 'Z%'
and crd.upc_14 in (@upc_code)
```

If you must have this in a SP, you'll need to get a little fancier to hand in the multi-value parameter and handle the splitting yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9862901/400375

Comment: Good to know.  I appreciate the info and link.  I will try that out now.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, I embedded the SQL query in the report, but the result was still the same: when I selected more than one code, I got no results.  The "allow multiple values" box is checked, by the way.

Comment: The query matched what I have above? with `in (@ParameterName)` as the use of the parameter? What SQL database and version were you using? I've done this hundreds of times without problems.

Comment: Yes, I used the query above with the in (@parametename).  I am using SQL Server Management Studio V17.0

Comment: Jamie, your code did work.  Another post mentioned that I needed to add  =Join(Parameters!TerritoryMulti.Value, ",") in the SSRS dataset properties, but that actually prevented the code from working.  After removing it, the code was fine.  Thanks again.