# SSRS Stored Procedure with parameter not working fine

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have one SSRS report which imports data from direct query.(I wrote similar to that down)

```
select a.[Ultimate Parent Account],b.[Account Internal ID],b.[Parent Account ],count(*) as Opportunities
from T_OPTYLINEVIEW_REP a
inner join T_OPTYVIEW_REP b on a.[Opportunity ID]=b.[Opportunity Internal ID]
where a.[Ultimate Parent Account] in (@Ultimate_Acct_ID)
group by a.[Ultimate Parent Account],b.[Account Internal ID],b.[Parent Account ]
```

Now if I want this to be stored procedure I did->

```
create procedure testing_proc(@ultimateaccount varchar(100))
as
select a.[Ultimate Parent Account],b.[Account Internal ID],b.[Parent Account ],count(*) as Opportunities
from T_OPTYLINEVIEW_REP a
inner join T_OPTYVIEW_REP b on a.[Opportunity ID]=b.[Opportunity Internal ID]
where a.[Ultimate Parent Account] IN (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@ultimateaccount, ','))
group by a.[Ultimate Parent Account],b.[Account Internal ID],b.[Parent Account ]
```

When I put this proc in SSRS it was acting weird like it was pulling few rows only when I selected 'all' in the parameter.
Like it was pulling only 4 to 5 rows sometimes only 3 rows and all the time the rows were different.

But when I use the direct query and keep the parameter to select 'all' it pulls all the data which is around 9000 rows.

So why my proc is not working fine? I have used the STRING_SPLIT too if the problem is of commas in multiple selection.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: SSRS and syntax claims that the question is SQL Server-related. The tag [mysql] removed.

Comment: When you use a multi-value parameter in SSRS it doesn't translate directly to a parameter you would use in SQL Server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSRS multi-value parameter using a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256925/ssrs-multi-value-parameter-using-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: no it didn't @DaleK
I created the parameter using join(parameter....)
My proc is same only to the given answer so no need to make any change in that
but now also only 4 to 5 rows are getting fetched

Comment: Using multivalued parameters with direct queries vs stored procedures is quite different. You just have to debug them individually. Although in fact, I think I spotted your error `varchar(100)` is not long enough to contain many ids... you need `varchar(max)`.

Comment: yaa thanks a lot @DaleK 
the issue was with the varchar(100) only
now i am getting more rows 
Again thanks a lot for this 
but still i am getting 8777 rows from stored proc and 9394 from direct query .
For some of the ultimate acct ids like this 'Taylor Communications, Inc.' I am not getting any data in stored procedure but the data is present for direct query.
You have helped a lot
It would be so great of you if you can help with this thing too

Comment: If you have a comma in your data and then you split on a comma its going to cause you issues. You should be using a PK id selecting records.

Comment: yaa @DaleK the issue is with the comma only
Thanks a lot mate
U r doing so good by commenting so quickly and helping people like us.
Thanks again!!!!