# SSRS - multi-value parameter is throwing error when more than one value is selected

Tags: reporting-services, multi-select

I am using Visual Studios 2015 with SSDT installed. I cannot show my query as it has confidential columns in it. Let's just say I have two temporary tables that gather general data which are joined in the select statement and uses a where clause that accepts a multi-value parameter of text datatype (column is char(8)) to filter the information in the report. I have checked allow multiple values in the parameter properties. There are no available values, the user types the values in. (I've also tried supplying values in drop down list with same results).

```
Where smpl_lvl_cd in (@SampleLevel)
```

I would think this is quite simple and when the user selects one value, everything works well. As soon as you choose more than one value, you get the error "An expression of non-Boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','."

For example: Sample Levels 'Q' and 'V' are selected. The way I understand it, SSRS send 'Q,V' to the query. (Or does it send "Q,V,'?) With this in mind, I've tried using:

```
Where smpl_lvl_cd in (select value from string_split(@SampeLevel, ','))
```

with similar results "Procedure or function string_split has too many arguments specified....." followed by the same Boolean message.

This parameter is not being sent to a stored procedure but I've tried using the join function on the parameter in combination with the string_split in the query. I end up getting no data for more than one selection.

Please help.

Comment: How does the user enter the parameter values manually? If they are adding commas then that's the issue, you just need to type the values and hit enter between values so they appear on separate lines

Answer (score 0):

See this article: [SSRS multi-value parameter using a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256925/ssrs-multi-value-parameter-using-a-stored-procedure?rq=1).  You have to change your multi-valued parameter array into a string before sending into your dataset. therefore send the expression  `=Join(SampeLevel!Value,",")`  instead of  `[@SampeLevel]`