# Querying with multiple value parameter in SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: reportbuilder, report-builder2.0

I am basically trying to do what is asked in this question:

[Passing multiple values for a single parameter in Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services)

but it is not working for me.

My parameter has a data type of `text`. I have a feeling that my parameter is being surrounded by quotes when it is inserted into my query.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    AllUserData.tp_ID, Title as TestSite, tp_Title as TestCase, nvarchar6 as ItemNumber, 
    nvarchar7 as DefectType, nvarchar8 as Status, nvarchar9 as QuestionID, 
    ntext2 as Question, AllUserData.tp_Version as Version, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), AllUserData.tp_Modified, 111) AS DateModified
FROM 
    [dbTOG].[dbo].[AllUserData] 
INNER JOIN
    dbTOG.dbo.AllLists on dbTOG.dbo.AllUserData.tp_ListId = dbTOG.dbo.AllLists.tp_ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbTOG.dbo.Webs on dbTOG.dbo.AllLists.tp_WebId = dbTOG.dbo.Webs.Id
WHERE 
    (nvarchar8 = 'PASS' OR
     nvarchar8 = 'FAIL' OR
     nvarchar8 = 'N/A' OR
     nvarchar8 = 'TBD' OR
     nvarchar8 = 'TBRT' OR
     nvarchar8 = 'FIXED') 
    AND Title = @TestSite 
    AND tp_Title IN (@TestCase)
```

**Parameter expression** for @TestCase

```
=Join(Parameters!TestCase.Value, ",")
```

Answer (score 5):

This is quite late but I was struggling with pretty much the same thing. Eventually I found the answer from the link in the OT, however not the accepted one.

I changed the **parameter expression** to:

```
=SPLIT(JOIN(Parameters!<your param name>.Value,","),",")
```

This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: right click in dataset > "Dataset Properties" > "Parameters" tab > click in buttom "Fx" in the parameter

Comment: I'm on a different project now so no longer have access to this, I don't understand your comment, what are you trying to say?

Comment: I'm just trying to explain where to put the formula for multiple values in parameters