# How to pass multiple values to a single parameter in a Reporting Services report

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, bids, sql-server-2012-express

I have a report in Reporting Services with a text box field in a table that has a Go to report Action. I need a Parameter for specific values to be able to pass to that report. The IN (@Parameter) will not work with multiple values. I have two tables with similar data. One has data for ALL countries and one has data just for Canada. I have one report that I want to Jump To for each table. When the field in the ALL countries table is clicked, I want to pass all the values to a parameter in the Dataset. When the field on the Canada table is clicked, I want to pass just the values for Canada to the Dataset. I can get it to work for one value, but not multiple values. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services

Comment: This doesn't quite solve my problem or maybe I'm not doing something right still.  The issue is that I have two tables and I want each to Go to the same report but pass a different value to the same parameter.  How do I set the value in the Go to section for each text box properties?

Comment: Can you show what is the Goto Syntax you used for both the text boxes. Can you also show which one works and which one doesn't. To me it looks like all you need to do is create different URL for both the text boxes passing different values.

Comment: I don't use a Go to URL.  I've never done that before.  I've always used Go to report.  All I have in both right now is the another value I'm passing to the dataset that only needs to accept one value.  Part of my issue is figuring out what needs to go there...

Comment: I still think you need to use JOIN. But if you cannot give me some more description about your issue like screenshots and code, it will be difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution or already figured out the solution?

Comment: Yes, I am still looking for a viable solution.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer on this if anyone can assist...