# Passing multiple values through an option of a multivalue parameter -SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

i'm attempting to pass multiple values from a field through a parameter for an SSRS report. This is a multivalue parameter. The code below simply pulls the records for the latest **set @department** statement and not the rest of the values i want it to pull. What can i add to this statement to pass all of the values from the field to that one option in the multivalue parameter. Thanks a lot for your help.

```
while (@department = 'RSI ALL')
begin
if @department = 'RSI ALL' 
begin
set @department = 'RSI-IT'
set @department = 'RSI'
set @department = 'RSI-JAX'
set @department = 'IT'
end
if (@department <> 'RSI ALL')
break
else 
continue
end
```

Comment: "What can i add to this statement to pass all of the values from the field", what field?, can you clarify what it is that you want?

Comment: there are multiple answers all over the web once you care to search. One of which can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services

Comment: there is a **dept** field, which i'm using for a multivalue parameter in an SSRS report, the field contains values which i want to 'bundle' into one selection. For example, there are values (RSI, RSI-IT, RSI-JAX, IT) which i would like to combine into one selection called 'RSI ALL', then when that 'RSI ALL' is selected from the drop down, all of the records which are of the values (RSI, RSI-IT, RSI-JAX, IT) should be displayed. There are other instances like this. Thanks for the reply.