# How do I utilize a multi-value Parameter in a query for SSRS report?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, bids, sql-server-2012-express

I am working on a report in SSRS that has a Parameter that can have multiple values.  I can pass one Parameter value to the query just fine.  I am using IN @Paramter in the query for multiple values and I also made the Parameter accept multiple values.  However, when I want ALL the values, the query does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the query does not work'? Do you get any kind or error? Does the query work when you select a multiple values but not all values?

Comment: The report returns no data when I try to pass multiple values.  I'm not sure how to setup the parameter on the report and how to assign the values properly.

Comment: You don't have a dataset for the values associated with the parameter do you?

Answer (score 3):

There are several answers on SO related to passing multi-valued parameters to a dataset query in SSRS.  See this --> [Passing multiple values for a single parameter in Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services).

I wasn't able to reproduce the scenario you described (choosing one value works, but ALL values don't work).  However, I implemented one of the answers from the link above (Minks) using SQL Server 2008 as the data source.  Below are the details:

I have a parameter named @ReportParameter1 that is populated from the following Dataset query (Value field = id, Label field = description):

```
select 1 as id, 'choice1' as description union
select 2 as id, 'choice2' as description union
select 3 as id, 'choice3' as description union
select 4 as id, 'choice4' as description
```

Then I have my report Dataset query as:

```
select * from 
(select 1 as id union
 select 2 as id union
 select 3 as id union
 select 4 as id) x
 where id in (@ReportParameter1)
```

Under the Parameters tab for the report Dataset, I have the following expression set for @ReportParameter1:

```
=Split(Join(Parameters!@ReportParameter1.Value,","),",")
```

If I choose ALL values for @ReportParameter1, then the query effectively becomes:

```
select * from 
(select 1 as id union
 select 2 as id union
 select 3 as id union
 select 4 as id) x
 where id in (1,2,3,4)
```