# Passing multiple value parameters in SSRS to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I am trying to pass a multiple value string parameter to a table type parameter in a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure. I paste this code in the dataset of SSRS:

```
DECLARE @mylist clinic_list_tbltype
INSERT @mylist(n) VALUES (@pm_ChooseClinics)
EXEC sp_Skillset_Summary_With_Callbacks_Report @mylist, @pm_ChooseInterval, @pm_StartDateTime, @pm_EndDateTime
```

clinic_list_tbltype is a table type I created with one varchar(50) field named "n". I can call this stored procedure from SSMS o.k. like this (and it comes back very fast):

```
DECLARE @mylist clinic_list_tbltype
INSERT @mylist(n) VALUES ('clinicA'), ('clinicB')
EXEC sp_Skillset_Summary_With_Callbacks_Report  @mylist, 'Daily', '6/3/2014', '6/9/2014'
```

I can run in SSRS for only one clinic (but very slow), but if I try more than one it gives an error saying that

> there are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified
>   in the Values clause

. Even running for one clnic it works, but it takes a very very long time compared to running the query in SSMS. Like 2 minutes vs. 1 second. Must be because I'm passing ('clinicA', 'clinicB') instead of ('clinicA'), ('clinicB').

How to do?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing multiple values for a single parameter in Reporting Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services)

Answer (score 7):

Right I need to give you some back ground 1st.

When you allow SSRS parameter to select multiple values, The selection of multiple values creates a comma deliminated string of value as one string

```
  'value1,value2,value3'
```

To check values in a string using `IN` operator we need strings concatenated with commas something like this ....

```
  'value1','value2','value3'
```

**Your Proc**

Now in your proc when you insert values explicitly it inserts multiple values into your table.

```
  INSERT INTO Table_Value_Param
  VALUES ('value1'),       --<-- 1st value/Row
         ('value2'),       --<-- 2nd Value/Row
         ('value3')        --<-- 3rd Value/Row
```

and this gives you back the expected results as when inside your procedure you execute a statement like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_Name
WHERE ColumnName IN (SELECT ColumnName 
                     FROM Table_Value_Param)
```

On the other hand when you try to insert into table using SSRS report Parameter you table inserts value like

```
  INSERT INTO Table_Value_Param
  VALUES ('value1,value2,value3')   --<-- One Row/Value containing all the values comma separated
```

**Solution**

Creating `TVP` in this situation doesnt really help, What I do is make use of `dbo.Split()` function inside my procedure.

You can find many definitions for split function online, for a some cool ones have a look here  [`Split Function equivalent in tsql?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)

Once you have created this split function just use this function inside your procedure definition you dont even need the Table valued parameters then.

Something like this...

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM Table_Name 
  WHERE ColumnName IN ( 
                       SELECT Value
                       FROM dbo.Split(@Report_Param, ',')
                       )
```

Comment: I'll have a look at that, thanks. Are you sure that SSRS would pass a multivalue parameter as 'value1,value2,value3'? I would expect both that and 'value1','value2','value3' to be incorrect, and given the error "...fewer columns...etc". I would expect it be the latter. If it was the former I would expect it to run, but bring back no data.

Comment: Know it's an old post but for anyone wondering @urbanmojo 's correct in that the multivalue parameter formatting is 'val1','val2'... 

I was just working on a query in SSRS and used it like:

`WHERE ColumnName IN (@MultivalueParam)`

without any issues. Just make sure you enclose it with the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Vendors_Filter nvarchar(max) = 'a,b,c'
declare @Vendors nvarchar(max) 
set @Vendors =''''+replace(@Vendors_Filter,',',''',''')+'''' 
select @Vendors
```