# Passing multi-value parameter to another parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with 2 parameters - drop down selections of Buildings (@buildings) and Departments (@departments). When a Building is selected, the list of Departments is limited to Departments within that Building.

This is straightforward when the report parameter is not set to single-selection - the query parameter of Department is set to `@building`, so the above works.

However, a new requirement is to be able to multi-select Buildings. I've amended my background queries to use `Building in (@building)` rather than `@building = Building` and changed the Building query parameter of the main report to `=String.Join(Parameters!Building.Value, ",")` so everything passes through correctly.

However changing the Building query parameter for the Department parameter to this makes the Department drop-down box appear disabled. Setting the parameter to `=Parameters!Building.Value` makes the list work, but only when a single Building is selected - it appears as an empty list beyond that.

How can I set up a parameter to take a multi-value parameter as an argument?

---

**Edit: Full details**

Main report query:

```
create proc dbo.GetReport (
    @buildings varchar(max), @departments varchar(max)) as
select <columns>
from dbo.MainReport
where Building in (@buildings) and Department in (@departments)
```

Main report parameter settings:

```
@buildings: =Join(Parameters!Buildings.Value, ",")
@departments: =Join(Parameters!Departments.Value, ",")
```

Buildings parameter query:

```
create proc dbo.GetBuildings as
select <columns> from dbo.Buildings
```

Departments parameter query:

```
create proc dbo.GetDepartments(
    @buildings varchar(max))
select <columns> from dbo.Departments 
where Building in (@buildings)
```

Departments parameter setting:

```
// This will make the Departments drop-down disabled
@buildings: =Join(Parameters!Buildings.Value, ",")
// So will this
@buildings: =Split(Join(Parameters!Buildings.Value, ","), ",")
// This will only work when only one building is selected
@buildings: =Parameters!Buildings.Value
```

Comment: You handle it in the query for the Department parameter the same way you handle it in the query for the main report, or any other query.

Comment: It sounds like it should be working. Did you update the query that you are using for your Department parameter to use **IN** Parameters!Building.Value?

Comment: Yes, the queries are updated

Comment: I've added the full details of the queries / parameter settings in my report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot handle Multi-valued parameters from SSRS in stored procedures in this way (with the IN() clause).   That method only works when you generate your SQL query in SSRS (without calling a stored procedure).

To use a Multi-valued parameter in a stored procedure, you must call a split function on the parameter in the stored procedure, and JOIN to it to get the results.

The answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139490/passing-multiple-value-parameters-in-ssrs-to-stored-procedure) spells it out in even more detail.