# Report Builder timesout when using multiple values in parameter

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I have a report wich seems like

```
   Select * From Accounts where Account_Num in (:pAccount)
```

The parameter is defined to allow multiple values, so when I run the report for just one value for example:

```
   00001
```

the report runs correct but when use more than one value it takes to long to run or it simply gives a timeout.

```
   00001
   00002
```

I use a line break for each value and the report builder adds an "," to each value.

Do I need to configure something addtional to run the report correctly? Thank in advance for your help.

I'm using Report Builder 3.0 and Oracle 8 as DBMS.

Comment: Maybe it uses an index access or even a primary key access when given one parameter, but does a full-table-scan when given more than one. Try running the same query in sqlplus and see what happens.

Comment: When I run the query in SQLDev it brings the results in 0.298 seconds for the same 2 values. Let my try in SQLPLUS, thanks!

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about reporting services. Did you check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services ?