# Passing multiple values in querystring in .aspx to report at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012, query-string, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to pass multiple value in query string in my ASP.Net web report in VS2012. The page has to pass multiple values to the report as a parameter . When I sent a single value (for eg: abc,) the data is being pulled up correctly but however when I am passing multiple values separated by a comma (eg abc,xyz) it is not displaying the results These multiple values separated by a comma are being passed to the page as query strings and we then are reading them and passing it to the report.

**Please note:
For the parameter in the report, I set the default list of values and I also defined available set of values. Now when I am trying to trying pass the values to this parameter from c# code, it is still not accepting the values that I supplied instead it is taking all the values from available list. I think the problem is that the SSRS is not accepting values separated by a comma when "Allow multiple values" check box is checked. Please advise.**

This is what I am trying so far:

```
ReportParameter pb1 = new ReportParameter();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["pm1"])) { 
        pb1.Name = "PurchaseMaterial1";
        string[] strPb1 = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["pm1"]).Split(',');
        string value = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["pm1"]);
        if (strPb1.Length > 0)
        {
            int i = 0;
            value = "";
            while (i < strPb1.Length)
            {
                if (value == string.Empty)
                {
                    value = "'" + strPb1[i] + "'";
                }
                else
                {
                    value += ",'" + strPb1[i] + "'";
                }
                i += 1;
            }
        }
        pb1.Values.Clear();
        pb1.Values.Add(value);
```

An alternative to using a comma delimited parameter is reusing the same parameter like: www.test.com/?pm1=test1&pm1=test2&pm1=test3.
But this approach is not acceptable by the business and would like to have ability to separate values by coma itself.

Please help, thanks much in advance :)

Comment: Is there any reason in particular you're not using the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552587/unable-to-pass-multiple-values-in-querystring-in-aspx-to-report-at-runtime) you asked on this topic?

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with any of the solution offered so trying to rephrase my question with more details.

Comment: Then you should edit the question rather then creating a new one.

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: I personally do not have a solution. But that's irrelevant. You should use your original question, adding detail or clarifying it as appropriate. Make sure you also respond to the comments, as those looked promising.

Comment: Sure...I'll make sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A ReportParameter object takes a string collection as a value.  So what you want is something like this (I speak VB, so please accept my apologies and translate accordingly):

```
string qryParams() = split(queryString, ",");

for each qryParam in qryParams
    pb1.values.add(qryParam);
next
```

What you were doing was adding one parameter with commas in it and not adding multiple params.