# SSRS 2012 - Pass list of values to multi-select parameter in linked report

Tags: multi-select, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report (report A) that currently generates a comma-delimited list of user ids based on a labor category.  I'm trying to link report A to another report (report B), and pass that list of user ids (contained in a single field), to report B to use in its multi-select parameter 'User Id'.

The field value being passed from A to B is "1,2,3,4", etc., but when report B loads, the parameter drop down shows no value selected.

Is there a specific format the string needs to be in for the multi-select parameter to pick it up?

I've tried splitting the field, then using the JOIN() command, but no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CodeGrue's answer to a similar question gives a solution for passing multi-valued integer parameters:

[Passing multiple values for a single parameter in Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services)