# SQL iReport WHERE with various numbers from Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, jasper-reports, where-clause

A Parameter returns a list of various numeric values:

```
[12345, 1234, 123]
```

The length and quantity vary, e.g. it could be a list of 100 or a list of only 5 values.

Now I want to use those values in the WHERE of a Microsoft SQL-Server query. I thought of using IN. Therefore I need to convert those values into the right syntax:

```
('12345', '1234', '123')
```

Some ideas for the right conversion?

Other better(easier) solutions without using LIKE?

Edit: Sorry. My case description wasn't clear at all. The SQL Query is inside iReport and the Parameter (e.g. $P{DATUM_BIS}) is returned by external software.

Comment: You can't use `LIKE`. Use `IN`.

Comment: `where f in (a, b, c, d ...)` is the closest form but you would need to protect against injection if there is any possibility of non-numeric values.  Looping the string, inserting into a temp table/table variable and joining or using a sub-query is another option.

Comment: Soooo many duplicates.   Please do some research before asking.   Here's one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: @JanNatter You should use `$X{}` syntax. [JasperReports - Query Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/index.html#query)

Comment: @AlexK Thank you. `$X{IN, <column_name>, <parameter_name>} `worked perfect for me

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not approach this by munging strings.  If you are generating the list of values in the database, then you want to do all the work in the database -- and not put the values in a parameter.

But, if you are stuck with this method for some reason, you *can* use `like`:

```
where replace(replace(@param, '[', ', '), ']', ', ')) like '%, ' + cast(col as varchar(255)) + ', %'
```

This will not make use of indexes, but it does implement the logic that you want as a (relatively) simple query.

I should note that SQL Server 2016 introduces `string_split()` which offers other options with better performance.