# Multiple values in parameter call stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, report

Im solving report in visual studio data tool. I have prepared interface and charts and calculating. I have stored procedure on ms server, which i call from report.

Stored procedure has 4 parameters (year,month,teritory,product and type)
In report i have declare teritory and product like with multiple values options.

I need refer this values in parameter teritory and product into stored procedure.

Any idea how its works? Some tips? I need use this multiple values in clause IN
(for ex.  where territory in (@territory)    - its like a where territory in ('110','120','D01')  )

Here is part of begin of my procedure

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[P_WaterfallSLS] @year int,@month int, @territory nvarchar(250),@productgtroup varchar(25),@type int

as

SET NOCOUNT On
SET FMTONLY OFF
declare @valueLeft float
declare @lost float
declare @downTrader float
declare @upTrader float
declare @gained float
declare @valueRight float


select c.ICO,tar.teritoriumSales,c.title,tb.yearr,tb.monthr,wdays,sum(revenue) as revenue,sum(tb.parcels) as parcels into #h1 from workspace..TB_SALES_CUB tb
```

.....

And here is prints from my visual studio.
[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Check out this [Passing multiple values for a single parameter in Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services)

Comment: I would go so far as to say it's a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing multiple values for a single parameter in Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services)