# Multi Value Parameter in SSRS -Values are showing NUll when selected

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I tried using 
Where Location IN(@Location)
in my storedprocedure

In SSRS
i used =join(Parameters!Location.Value,",")

When i select all values the result is null 
The value is in string format 
Eg: 'XXXX,YY','yyy,mm'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `Sql` stored procedure code so that it could recognize the comma separated values being passed from `SSRS`.

One way would be using `table-value function` that can split a comma-delimited string back out into a mini table - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services/512300#512300)

Once done the code in your stored procedure should be like this -

```
WHERE Location IN (SELECT Param FROM dbo.fn_MVParam(@Location,','))
```