# Use SSRS report parameter to accept comma separated integer from ASP.NET web app

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssrs-2012

1. In SSRS I have a parameter which is of type integer.

[image]

2. Parameter values are bound from dataset, so that after the report gets loaded we can select parameter and run the report.

[image]

3. My situation is I have to pass the same parameter from web app without disturbing the existing functionality. Like "1,2,3" these are Id's which exists in the dropdown.

**Elaborating the issue:**

---

I have a query in SSRS dataset which takes a parameter `employeeIds` (this is a multi select parameter) query is something like this where `EmployeeTable.Id in (@employeeIds)`

When I used SQL profiler and saw the query executed against my database, it looks like this  `EmployeeTable.Id in (21,34,56,81)`

Which is good, all works well till here. Now I need to call same report from a ASPX page without showing SSRS Filters pane (So I have to construct my params and pass to SSRS report)

Here is how I tried to passed the parameter

```
parameters(10) = New ReportParameter("employeeIds", "21,34,56,81")
```

This is throwing error as below

> Cannot cast varchar to integer

If I change my Report parameter to string that will break SSRS Parameter filter logic, so I cannot do that. Without disturbing current working SSRS report how can I pass this param from code to Report?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: so.. what do you have so far and what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: When I pass comma separated input exception occurs stating - cannot convert string to integer

Comment: what happens if you were to change the datatype to text for your parameter?

Comment: If I change it to text, no error but SSRS do not recognize and apply value. With type text and pass one value e.g."1" it works fine

Comment: @Harry please see my updated question where I have elaborated with all details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing multiple values for a single parameter in Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right you're trying to open the report in an aspx page and want to open it with your parameter `employeeIds` set to specific values. So you're looking into setting the parameter value of `employeeIds` to many values at once.

That could look like this:

```
parameters(10) = New ReportParameter("employeeIds", new string[] {"21","34","56","81"})
```

When providing multiple values to a parameter you need to put them in an Array. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-webforms-reportviewer-control?view=sql-server-ver15) for more info.